Meaning of 透過閱讀論語，涵養為學與處事的良好態度
透過閱讀論語，涵養為學與處事的良好態度。
What does 涵養 mean? I found two definitions:

To cultivate (verb)
Good morals (noun)

為學 means knowledge, so if (1), then it's to cultivate knowledge, but if (2), then it means a good knowledge of morals. These seem completely different things. Thanks for the help.

為 means do and 學 means study. So it means "do study". 為學的態度 means "the attitude of studying". So the sentence is "cultivate a good attitude of studying and and doing things".

涵 has the meaning of "cover" (entire area of something)
養 here means "cultivate"
涵養 here means "broadly cultivate" (涵 acts as an adverb and 養 is the verb)- not just cultivate one or few good attitudes but wildly cultivate all the good attitudes
In another context when 涵養 is used as a noun, it means 'self-possession; self-restraint
Example: 他有很好的涵養 - he has good self-restraint

透过: through
涵養: 修养: 例: 道德修养 moral (self) cultivation
涵: 包容，包含
加强党性修养
enhance the ethical standards of The Party
内涵: intention, connotation, content
涵义: meaning, connotation, purport
透過閱讀《論語》，涵養為學與處事的良好態度。
Through reading The Analects,
涵養為學與處事的良好態度。
cultivate (the dual aspects of) learning and worldly competence.
